# does dynamic laravel database properties affect the application speed?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel, laravel-5.1

i'm using Laravel 5.1 in my new application its already at beginning point but i guess in a near future it would be a large app with lots of data and queries may each user asks.

Laravel uses somehow dynamic properties for mysql database fields for example you just say

```
$role = new Role();
$role->slug = 'admin';
```

you didn't define anything like

```
Class Role extends Model{
   protected $_slug;

   public function getSlug(){
       return $this->_slug;
   }
   public function setSlug( $slug ){
       $this->_slug = $slug;
       return $this;
   }
   ...
```

this ( in old way) so to say slug field is actually exists and i'm using it, you're just assign it dynamically,

my question is does this scheme affects the speed of application in a large scale of data or it doesn't matter ?

should i define each table fields , for better performance or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel way dosen't extend the complexity of memory becasue all the data are loaded to the `$attributes` protected property - so they are kept there which means that they need the same memory.

In fact for large project we can feal the problem about computational complexity and the time of reciving the data with `$this->entry` - because this is the operation within magic `__get()` method. The true is that you shouldn't use eloquent for large sets of data - it will kill the CPU for sure. In big sets of data Laravel becoming useless unfortunattely.